# how to reset atmega16a fuse bits?

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, embedded, fuse-bits, usbasp

I am using usbasp with atmega16a. I try to use external crystal 16MHZ with 22p capacitor. With mistake i use this command to change the fuse setting.

```
avrdude -c usbasp -p atmega16 -U lfuse:w:0b00000000:m hfuse:w:0b10011001:m
```

The atmega16a is dead. How to fix it?

pls. Any solution:

Comment: I first assumed you had by mistake set the fuse settings  incorrectly. But I guess it is unlikely you would make the same mistake twice. Nevertheless I would first check the XTAL2 pin with a 'scope to see if the clock was running.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick What does it mean check XTAL2 pin with a 'scope to see if the clock was running'? But then i try to run with atmega8l still not working internal crystal. How i reset usbasp to factory setting?

Comment: @AlexCerry There is no "internal crystal" in Atmega, only simple RC oscillator.

Comment: @lustful-rat how i solve this problem?

Comment: I change the question now usbasp working with atmega8l. But not working with atmega16a.

Comment: Use HVPP to fix the fuses.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have only usbasp. I try to search about high voltage parallel programming. But i cannot find any proper solution. Please can you guide how i fix?

Comment: Get or make a HVPP programmer. Use it to fix the fuses.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How to make hvpp programmer?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If i provide 12v to reset pin. Is it will work?

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45077/discussion-between-alex-cerry-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using windows os there are avr studio 4 is available. in this ide you can modify your fuse bits and it is one type gui based software which indicates your all fuse bytes and all.